# Making comment section for a blog based on PHP, MySQL and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, comments

I'm struggling for a few days right now with making a comment section for a really simple blog based on PHP, MySQL and HTML. I can add posts, edit them but I have a problem with showing comments. My code shows first post and comment only but rest of the posts without comments. This is the code i should show you I think.

```
$wyswkom = mysqli_query($polacz, "SELECT * FROM kom");
$komy = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wyswkom);
$wynik = mysqli_query($polacz, "SELECT * FROM news");
while($news = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wynik)){
    if($news['id'] == $komy['idnewsa']) {
        print $news['autor'].": ".$news['tekst']." / id: ".$news['id']."</br>"."Komentarze: ".$komy['tekst']." -".$komy['autor']."<br>";
    } else { 
        echo $news['autor'].": ".$news['tekst']." / id: ".$news['id']."</br>"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you connect news and their comments?

Comment: They are in one database

Comment: I can show you all of the code if you want

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` only fetches one row at the time so you're just fetching one comment. What is the expected result here? Since you're looping on the news items, you would only show one comment per news item either way.

Comment: I wanted to show all of the news with comment for each news, what should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Fetch a result row
>   as an associative array

Property `$wynik` always include only first comment from your DB.

Right way how to do this is use WHERE in your SQL statements and load only data you will need. Then iterate over like you are doing for news.

```
SELECT * FROM kom WHERE idnews = 1
```

Best way how to learn this would by use some tutorial. This is simple problem with lots of good examples outside.

Comment: Could you recommend me any tutorial?

Comment: By the way, this line with selecting everything from 'kom', where idnews = 1 would show only comments for news with id = 1, so how can i print comments for all of the news?

Comment: Take a note, this is only for you to understand principle, its far for perfect.

https://pastebin.com/A5wzXsUY

You should look at SQL Injection and how to properly pass params to SQL query.